# Python 3 fazer o programa descobrir o quanto de um determinado dígito tem numa string ou um número

Tags: python, python-3.x

É pra python 3:

Estou tentando fazer um programa bem básico pra descobrir o quanto de um determinado dígito tem em uma string ou um número.

Por exemplo, se o usuário escrever 1200, eu quero imprimir-"seu número tem 2 zeros"....ou se o usuário escrever "oi,tudo bem?"eu quero imprimir-"sua frase tem 2 'o's

Comment: Olá Mateus, Bem vindo ao StackOverflow PT! Tente explicar melhor sua pergunta com algum código que já tem, e detalhar um pouco mais. Você quer o caractere de maior ocorrência  em uma string ou quer todos?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Veja funcionando no [repl](https://repl.it/KZZD/1)
>   Codigo no [github](https://github.com/wellmotta/stackoverflow/blob/master/Python/contar-caracteres.py)

```
# coding: utf-8

# Informe uma frase
frase = input("Informe uma frase: ")
# Informe qual o caractere que deseja saber a quantidade contida na frase
caracter = input("Informe o caracter que deseja contar: ")
# método: count - Conta quantas vezes o caractere foi usado na frase
# Imprime a quantidade.
print("Sua frase tem: " + str(frase.count(caracter)) + " digito(s): " + str(caracter))
```

> Fonte: pergunta original em [Inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155617/count-occurrence-of-a-character-in-a-string)

Comment: Obrigado, o método funcionou para strings. Mas pra números, o programa diz que a função  .count não aceita números inteiros, tem como resolver isso?

Comment: Agora funciona, eu tinha me esquecido desse detalhe

Comment: Está certo que está funcionando, o link que colocas parece naum

Comment: Você tem que clicar no botão `player` ou usar o atalho `CRTL+ENTER` ai  no `painel` à sua direita ira rodar o código.

Comment: Veja creio que vc não entendeu o que está sendo pedido: " se o usuário escrever 1200, eu quero imprimir-"seu número tem 2 zeros"" , ou seja a saída quer número quer string deve mostrar quantas x se repetem, entendes?

Comment: Sim é exatamente o que o código faz, ele pede para o usuário informar uma frase, depois ele pede para você informar o caractere que você desejar contar.

Comment: Hum entendi agora sua abordagem...Vc está correto, falha minha

Comment: Funcionou, muito obrigado

Answer (score 3):

Extendendo a resposta do @Wéllingthon M. de Souza que respondeu e bem à tua pergunta, aqui deixo duas alternativas para o caso de quereres contar todos os caracteres:

```
from collections import Counter

frase = input("Informe uma frase: ")
count_chars = Counter(frase)

text = '\n'.join('A Frase tem {} {}'.format(v, k) for k, v in count_chars.items())
print(text)
```

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](https://repl.it/KZ6e)

De uma forma um pouco mais didática pode ser:

```
frase = input("Informe uma frase: ")

count_chars = {}
for char in frase:
    if char not in count_chars:
        count_chars[char] = 0
    count_chars[char] += 1

for char in count_chars:
    print('A Frase tem {} {}'.format(count_chars[char], char))
```

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](https://repl.it/KZ6b)

Answer (score 0):

Uma das forma para resolver esta questão é utilizando **[List Comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)**.
Par isso você pode usar a seguinte lógica:

1. Definir uma variável na qual será armazenada a referida string capturada;
2. Definir uma variável na qual será armazenado o carácter capturado a ser contado;
3. Implementar um list comrehension;
4. Exibir o resultado.

Com esta lógica pode implementar o seguinte código:

```
frase = input('Digite uma frase: ')
caract = input('Digite o carácter a ser contado: ')
cont = sum([1 for i in frase if i == caract])

print(f'Na frase existe {cont} caracteres "{caract}".')
```

**Como este código funciona?**

Inicialmente este código captura uma cadeia de caracteres - string - e, também, um carácter que desejamos contar. Posteriormente, uma lista será montada por compreensão de lista. Esta lista será montada com apenas valores **1** se, e somente se, a variável temporária "**i = caract**". Em seguida a função **sum()** somará a quantidade de **1** existente neta lista. Por fim será exibido a quantidade do carácter analisado.

**Testando o código:**

Imagine que ao executarmos o referido código digitássemos a seguinte frase:

```
diclorodifeniltricloroetano foi o um dos primeiros pesticidas modernos
```

e depois especificarmos o carácter "**o**" a ser contado.

A saída do código será:

```
Na frase existe 11 caracteres "o".
```