# Contagem de um especifico carácter em uma palavra no Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Recentemente fiz uma pergunta parecida, mas recebi respostas onde a minha entrada seria supostamente um número. É possível contar quantos caracteres especifico tem em uma palavra? Como em "exemplo" tem "2 e".

Comment: Quais específicos? Contar todas ocorrências de 2 ou de e ou de qualquer caractere?

Comment: A pergunta não é duplicata, pelo que vejo. Lá eram pra contar os caracteres iguais no final do input

Comment: Pelo que entendi, nenhuma das respostas da outra pergunta satisfazem a dúvida dessa.

Comment: Sim, a outra pergunta utiliza métodos matemáticos, e não para palavras, eu fiquei meio confuso de terem marcado este como duplicado

Comment: duplicata de [Python 3 fazer o programa descobrir o quanto de um determinado dígito tem numa string ou um número](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/232172/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use o [`str.count`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.count):

```
"exemplo".count("e")
=> 2
```